# Javascript: pegar o valor de um textarea (não está funcionando)

Tags: javascript, textarea

Eu tenho um textarea simples mas não consigo pegar o valor digitado nele, o que está bem estranho, código abaixo.

HTML

```
<textarea type="text" class="textarea" id="description2"></textarea> 
//Digitei aqui a palavra teste
```

Js

```
var oi = document.getElementById("description2").value; 
console.log(oi); 
//resultado: "" 
// deveria ser "teste"
```

Elemento pego:

```
accessKey: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: _ngcontent-c1, 1: class, 2: formcontrolname, 3: id, 4: required, 5: type, 6: ng-reflect-required, 7: ng-reflect-name, _ngcontent-c1: _ngcontent-c1, class: class, formcontrolname: formcontrolname, id: id, required: required, …}
autocapitalize: ""
autocomplete: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "http://localhost:4200/"
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList []
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList(5) ["textarea", "error-field", "ng-touched", "ng-dirty", "ng-valid", value: "textarea error-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"]
className: "textarea error-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"
clientHeight: 98
clientLeft: 1
clientTop: 1
clientWidth: 516
cols: 20
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
defaultValue: ""
dir: ""
dirName: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
form: form#form.form.ng-invalid.ng-touched.ng-dirty
hidden: false
id: "description2"
**innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
inputMode: ""**
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
labels: NodeList(2) [label.label, label.label]
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
localName: "textarea"
maxLength: -1
minLength: -1
name: ""
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: app-form-error-message.form-error-message-component
nextSibling: app-form-error-message.form-error-message-component
nodeName: "TEXTAREA"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 100
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: div.form-group
offsetTop: 40
offsetWidth: 518
onabort: (...)
onauxclick: (...)
onbeforecopy: (...)
onbeforecut: (...)
onbeforepaste: (...)
onblur: (...)
oncancel: (...)
oncanplay: (...)
oncanplaythrough: (...)
onchange: (...)
onclick: (...)
onclose: (...)
oncontextmenu: (...)
oncopy: (...)
oncuechange: (...)
oncut: (...)
ondblclick: (...)
ondrag: (...)
ondragend: (...)
ondragenter: (...)
ondragleave: (...)
ondragover: (...)
ondragstart: (...)
ondrop: (...)
ondurationchange: (...)
onemptied: (...)
onended: (...)
onerror: (...)
onfocus: (...)
onfullscreenchange: (...)
onfullscreenerror: (...)
ongotpointercapture: (...)
oninput: (...)
oninvalid: (...)
onkeydown: (...)
onkeypress: (...)
onkeyup: (...)
onload: (...)
onloadeddata: (...)
onloadedmetadata: (...)
onloadstart: (...)
onlostpointercapture: (...)
onmousedown: (...)
onmouseenter: (...)
onmouseleave: (...)
onmousemove: (...)
onmouseout: (...)
onmouseover: (...)
onmouseup: (...)
onmousewheel: (...)
onpaste: (...)
onpause: (...)
onplay: (...)
onplaying: (...)
onpointercancel: (...)
onpointerdown: (...)
onpointerenter: (...)
onpointerleave: (...)
onpointermove: (...)
onpointerout: (...)
onpointerover: (...)
onpointerup: (...)
onprogress: (...)
onratechange: (...)
onreset: (...)
onresize: (...)
onscroll: (...)
onsearch: (...)
onseeked: (...)
onseeking: (...)
onselect: (...)
onselectionchange: (...)
onselectstart: (...)
onstalled: (...)
onsubmit: (...)
onsuspend: (...)
ontimeupdate: (...)
ontoggle: (...)
onvolumechange: (...)
onwaiting: (...)
onwebkitfullscreenchange: (...)
onwebkitfullscreenerror: (...)
onwheel: (...)
outerHTML: "<textarea _ngcontent-c1="" class="textarea "  id="description2" required="" type="text" ></textarea>"
**outerText: ""**
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.form-group
parentNode: div.form-group
placeholder: ""
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: label.label
previousSibling: label.label
readOnly: false
required: true
rows: 2
scrollHeight: 98
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 516
selectionDirection: "forward"
selectionEnd: 0
selectionStart: 0
shadowRoot: null
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "TEXTAREA"
textContent: ""
textLength: 0
title: ""
translate: true
type: "textarea"
validationMessage: "Preencha este campo."
validity: ValidityState {valueMissing: true, typeMismatch: false, patternMismatch: false, tooLong: false, tooShort: false, …}
**value: ""**
willValidate: true
wrap: ""
__zone_symbol__blurfalse: [ZoneTask]
__zone_symbol__compositionendfalse: [ZoneTask]
__zone_symbol__compositionstartfalse: [ZoneTask]
__zone_symbol__inputfalse: [ZoneTask]
__proto__: HTMLTextAreaElement
```

Alguém sabe o que poderia estar acontecendo de errado aqui?

Comment: Porque o resultado deveria ser teste? Você preencheu o campo com "teste" e não apareceu nada?

Comment: É claro que não vai aparecer nada no console, você digitou **FORA** do textarea!!!

Comment: @LeAndrade o texto está vindo da tela, não sei o que você quis dizer.

Comment: Você colocou assim **//Digitei aqui a palavra teste** embaixo do textarea, o que passaa impressão é que você digitou fora!

Comment: @LeAndrade aquele comentário foi para vocês entenderem que eu digitei no elemento uma frase e o seu conteúdo não é vazio '...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que esse textarea estava dentro de um modal, de por algum motivo o campo é duplicado quando abre o modal, assim tenho 2 textarea com o mesmo id description.

Para solucionar fiz da seguinte forma:

```
var oi = document.getElementsByClassName("description2")[1]; 
console.log(oi); 
//resultado: "teste"
```

Comment: Olá Sabrina! Pode até funcionar, mas nem tudo que funciona é o correto. Lembre-se que um id deve ser único na página. Abs!

Comment: "campo duplicado"? humm, id deve ser único **sempre**, essa ideia pode não ser boa, e se criar um outro campo e esse passar a ser o índice 2, ou ainda 0? Não dá pra confiar nisso, melhor seria resolver o problema do nome

Comment: @RicardoPontual irei analisar o motivo, obrigada !

Answer (score 3):

Aqui funcionou perfeitamente.... se clicar o botão vai aparecer "alguma coisa", se alterar o valor e clicar novamente, aparece o que digitou, veja se não tem algum outro erro no seu código.

```html
<textarea type="text" class="textarea" id="description2">alguma coisa</textarea> 
<p>
   <button onclick='console.log(document.getElementById("description2").value);'>Pegar o valor</button>
</p>
```

Comment: A sua resposta teria sido a mais correta, entanto meu problema era o id duplicado do elemento, respondi a minha solução, Obrigada.

Comment: que bom que resolveu, mas sugiro pensar bem no caso no id duplicado

Comment: Irei verificar, obrigada !

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tenha que criar um botão chamando uma função javaScript setando o valor na variável:

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
}